# How can I track this shaky footage?

Tags: tracking

I want to get a 3D car on the road. I've tried tracking the footage, but it just doesn't work. The trackers don't stick. What are your ideas? Is there a better way to do it?

[Footage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOChw.jpg)

Comment: without seeing any of your settings you made for the tracking...we can just guess. So maybe it would be a good idea to provide blend file + footage so we can check it out

Comment: The video provided might be a bit of a challenge for tracking because shapes and shades are often indistinct and change.  From what I see, only 2D tracking is required, but if the trackers don't hold, you can do it manually and often more accurately.  It's called Rotoscoping.  Your video clip rotoscoped - (You can d/load it for a clearer image)

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtkhCKZLZs_PhQd8JNU3E3iP-0S4?e=4Ve9tI